# WPF cannot remove right border for DataGrid cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using DataGrid to show some information. However every row's right column displays an extra border line which does not align with the DataGrid border.

[image]

I've tried to set the cell BorderThickness to 0, but the right border line still exists.
The style xaml code is as below.

```
<!-- DataGrid Cell -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="RightCell">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
</Style>
<!--Text Block-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RegularTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSizeSuperSmall}" />
</Style>
```

The UI xaml code is as below.

```
<!-- DataGrid -->
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" 
Margin="0,0,10,0" 
x:Name="ResultDataGrid"
ItemsSource="{Binding ResultList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CanUserAddRows="False"
CanUserSortColumns="False"
CanUserDeleteRows="False"
CanUserReorderColumns="False"
GridLinesVisibility="All"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
RowHeaderWidth="0"
BorderBrush="{StaticResource CustomPureBlackBrush}"
BorderThickness="1"
Background="{StaticResource CustomPureWhiteBrush}">
<!-- Set Columns -->
<DataGrid.Columns>
<!-- First two columns have been deleted for simplicity.-->
<!-- Type Column-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle=" 
   {StaticResource FlattenRightHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource RightCell}" >
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
              <TextBlock Name="BuyTYpe" Text="test" Style="{StaticResource RegularTextBlock}" />
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Could someone give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is caused by the grid lines. Try turning them off:

```
GridLinesVisibility="None"
```

If you need those lines, you can use styles instead.

Comment: `GridLinesVisibility = "None"` could solve the problem. However it removes all border lines. I found that set `Margin = "0 0 -1 0"` could just removed the right border line.